# How to modify/fake document.referrer in any existing headless browser?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, zombie.js

Idea is to be able to modify `document.referrer` variable just before any JavaScript execution on website loaded by headless browser. What browser to use is not relevant, I have tried PhantomJS and Zombie without any luck.

My researches indicates that currently it is like so:

- [PhantomJS](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) - no, since it is const somewhat taken from `Referrer` header, but even providing this header .referrer is still an empty string in result.
- [zombie](https://github.com/assaf/zombie) - unknown.

Comment: Question is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this in phantomJS

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var dpage = webPage.create();

dpage.customHeaders = {
  "Referer": "https://www.facebook.com"
};
```

Comment: yes, setting `customHeaders` works (as in context that the headers are changing) but document.referrer stays unchanged

Comment: overwrite `page.onResourceRequested`